# Caching static resources on nginx and browser behaviour

Tags: nginx, browser-cache, multiple-browsers

I wanted to cache static resources so I set an expires header for static resources.

After setting the expires header, what I notice is:

1. Firefox and IE do not send requests to nginx for static resources
2. But all other browsers(Chrome, Safari, Opera) send a request to my nginx and nginx responds with 304 Not Modified

Are chrome, safari, opera caching my static resources? Is this normal behaviour? If not what should I do in addition so that static resources are cached by the other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a careful look at the subsequent HTTP requests from chrome/safari/opera:

It's most likely a conditional GET.
Also, the 304 Not Modified does not have a body.

So these browser cache too, just don't trust the content to stay the same before the expiration date.

They are just sniffing the milk in the fridge more often :-)